# Expo react native web bloqueo CORS al realizar llamadas

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cors, expo

Tengo un proyecto creado con expo que funciona en android, ios y web. Realizo llamadas post a un servidor y funciona perfectamente en android e ios pero en web aparece el error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at '...' from origin 'http://localhost:19006' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

El servidor funciona con apache y está configurado correctamente, sin embargo al hacer la llamada llega este error al servidor:

> Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException: "A Token was not found in the TokenStorage."

He probado también a subir la parte backend a un servidor real para ver si tenerlo en localhost era el problema pero sigue dando el mismo error.